# how to determine the neighbours of each node in a square graph ? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, nodes

Given the square representation of n = 256 nodes l want to display in a variable called neighbour{i} that returns all the neighbours of each node. for exemple in the square the number of nodes is n= 256 so l want to get the neighbours of each nodes in a cell array using matlab

```
for i=1:N
neighbour{i}=[neighbour{i} j]
end
                   ![%the code%
N = 16; M = 16;                  %# grid size
  CONNECTED = 8;                 %# 4-/8- connected points
%# which distance function
if CONNECTED == 4,     distFunc = 'cityblock';
elseif CONNECTED == 8, distFunc = 'chebychev'; end
%# compute adjacency matrix
\[X Y\] = meshgrid(1:N,1:M);
X = X(:); Y = Y(:);
adj = squareform( pdist(\[X Y\], distFunc) == 1 );
display(adj);
%# plot connected points on grid
\[xx yy\] = gplot(adj, \[X Y\]);
plot(xx, yy, 'ks-', 'MarkerFaceColor','r')
axis(\[0 N+1 0 M+1\])
\[X Y\] = meshgrid(1:N,1:M);
X = reshape(X',\[\],1) + 0.1; Y = reshape(Y',\[\],1) + 0.1;
text(X, Y(end:-1:1), cellstr(num2str((1:N*M)')) )
linked_node=cell(N,1);   
    % the most important step
  for X=1:N
      for Y=1:M
          if ((X~=Y) &&(squareform( pdist(\[X Y\], distFunc) == 1)))
               linked_node{X}= \[linked_node{X} Y\];
          end
      end
  end][1]
```

Comment: Your question is not that well defined. If I just read your question, I would suggest `convolution`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28537964/2545927)  on how to count the neighbours. However, your code seems to take a lot more than that into account than just counting neighbors. Could you please clarify what you mean by neighbours.

Comment: deatr kkuilla;                                                                                                        My aim is to have a cell array for each node that contains a set of its neighbours for exemple :
if the neighbours of  node 1 are : 2 ,5 ,7 ,18
then
neighbours{1}= {2,5,7,18}.
the aformentionned square graph is a graph of n=256 nodes
so l need to get and display this :
neighbours{1}= {2,5,7,18}    neighbours{2}= {1,26,4,18} ................ until neighbours{256}= {................}.  % two nodes are neighbours if they are linked

Comment: Have you got a list of neighbours?

Comment: this is what l need to construct

Comment: How do you know if two nodes are linked?

Comment: according to the adjacency matrix if in the matrix = 1 so there is a link if 0 so no link

Answer (score 1):

Actually the answer is to add this function that calculates the neghbours

```
function linked_node = find_neighbours(N, M, CONNECTED)

    %# which distance function
    if CONNECTED == 8
        distFunc = 'chebychev';
    else
        distFunc = 'cityblock';
    end

    linked_node=cell(N*M,1);   

      % the most important step
    for X=1:N
        for Y=1:M
            linked_node{sub2ind([N M], X,Y)} = [];
            if X - 1 > 0
                linked_node{sub2ind([N M], X,Y)}(end+1) = sub2ind([N M], X-1,Y);
                if strcmp(distFunc, 'chebychev')
                    if Y - 1 > 0
                        linked_node{sub2ind([N M], X,Y)}(end+1) = sub2ind([N M], X-1,Y-1);
                    end
                    if Y + 1 <= M
                        linked_node{sub2ind([N M], X,Y)}(end+1) = sub2ind([N M], X-1,Y+1);
                    end
                end
            end
            if X + 1 <= N
                linked_node{sub2ind([N M], X,Y)}(end+1) = sub2ind([N M], X+1,Y);
                if strcmp(distFunc, 'chebychev')
                    if Y - 1 > 0
                        linked_node{sub2ind([N M], X,Y)}(end+1) = sub2ind([N M], X+1,Y-1);
                    end
                    if Y + 1 <= M
                        linked_node{sub2ind([N M], X,Y)}(end+1) = sub2ind([N M], X+1,Y+1);
                    end
                end
            end
            if Y - 1 > 0
                linked_node{sub2ind([N M], X,Y)}(end+1) = sub2ind([N M], X,Y-1);
            end
            if Y + 1 <= M
                linked_node{sub2ind([N M], X,Y)}(end+1) = sub2ind([N M], X,Y+1);
            end
        end
    end

    end
```

Answer (score 0):

Given an adjacency matrix:

```
adj = [0 1 1 0 0;
       1 0 1 0 1;
       1 1 0 1 0;
       0 0 1 0 1;
       0 1 0 1 0];
```

You can convert the matrix to an adjacency list contained in a cell array like so:

```
%// Put matrix into cell array by rows
neighbors=mat2cell(adj,ones(1,size(adj,1)));
%// Convert logical row to adjacent indices
%// List sizes will vary, so 'UniformOutput' is false
neighbors=cellfun(@find,neighbors,'UniformOutput',false);
```

Results:

```
neighbors{2}
ans =

   1   3   5

neighbors
neighbors = 
{
  [1,1] =

     2   3

  [2,1] =

     1   3   5

  [3,1] =

     1   2   4

  [4,1] =

     3   5

  [5,1] =

     2   4

}
```